# How to generate a JSON report briefly summarizing system hardware?

Tags: hardware, cpu, bug-reporting, administration, lspci

The initial report sent to Ubuntu describing the system is no likely a summary pulled from `lspci`, `lscpu` and similar utilities.  This is for bug reporting.

Nonetheless, can I generate such a report, nicely summarized and in portable `JSON`, or something similar?

Comment: ... well, `lshw` has a `-json` output format. Does that do what you want?

Comment: that's pretty close @steeldriver but what I liked about the debug system info was its brevity versus `lshw` -- it just gave the highlights.  Maybe it's a matter of using `lshw` properly.